# OS X Finder: "Plain Text Document" has changed to "text", "Rich Text Document" to "rich text (RTF)", etc

Tags: macos, finder, file-association, file-types, filetype

Sometime recently some file type names have changed — not the file associations or default application, but the name of the file type itself. "Plain Text Document" has changed to "text", "Rich Text Document" to "rich text (RTF)", etc. as per:

[image]

I did a `find /Applications -name \*.plist -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep "rich text (RTF)"` and got hits in:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/CoreServices/MobileCoreTypes.bundle/Info.plist`

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetworkCoreTypes-Info.plist`

which do indeed list a whole whack of lowercase filetype names along with the offending ones.

And `sudo find /Library -name \*.plist -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep "rich text (RTF)"` found (along with a bunch of "Permission denied"s):

`/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 7.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/MobileCoreTypes.bundle/Info.plist`

`/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 7.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetworkCoreTypes-Info.plist`

Anyway, is anyone else seeing this? And/or see how it can be fixed/restored? Granted it's almost entirely aesthetic. But if aesthetics weren't important to me I wouldn't be using a Mac.